# Using SharedPreferences on a onClick method

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-button

I have a button in my activity, and I want to choose in my preference activity what internet website open when I click on it.

array.xml is like this:

```
<resources>
    <integer-array name="sites_values">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
    </integer-array>

    <string-array name="sites">
        <item>@string/site1</item>
        <item>@string/site2</item>
        <item>@string/site3</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

preference.xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="1"
        android:entries="@array/sites"
        android:entryValues="@array/sites_values"
        android:key="websites"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:summary="@string/summary"
        android:title="@string/title" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

This is PreferenceActivity:

```
public void public class MyPreference extends PreferenceActivity {
    public static final int DEFAULT_SITE = 1;
    public static final String FAV_SITE = "websites";

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

}
```

And finally this is the onClick method of MainActivity that doesn't work, with a "The application stopped unexpectedly" error:

```
public void click(View v) {
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String url;
    switch (pref.getInt(MyPreference.FAV_SITE,
                        MyPreference.DEFAULT_SITE)) {
        case 1:
        default:
            url = "http://www.google.com";
            break;
        case 2:
            url = "http://www.youtube.com";
            break;
        case 3:
            url = "http://www.facebook.com";
            break;
     }
     Intent BrowserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
     startActivity(BrowserIntent);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? onResume already uses SharedPreferences and works perfectly.

Edit:

This is the LogCat

```
07-08 16:18:27.540: W/dalvikvm(3041): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb67f44f0)
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     ... 11 more
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(ContextImpl.java:2857)
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at it.megaforum.megaapp.MainActivity.clickMegaforum(MainActivity.java:38)
07-08 16:18:27.570: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     ... 14 more
```

Edit 2:

I noticed that another error appears when I click on the preference in MyPreference activity.
If I change from integer-array to string-array this error disappears.

Comment: Try to use MainActivity.class instead of this and share your stacktrace

Comment: post the stack trace. it will be obvious from that.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the "this" in:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

doesn't fit as you are most likely in an inline class (the listener for the button), which means "this" references the listener class instead of the outer class (your activity).

Edit: To solve this you just need a reference on the preferences in the activity. Set it when the activity is created and then use it in the Listener. Or you just call a method from the activity that handels everything.

Comment: SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(preferencesActivity.this);

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand. Can you explain it better?

Comment: You are using "this" to get the default preferences for your activity. But in this case "this" doesn't reference the outer activity but the OnClickListener of the button. Try what Ryan Gray said and exchange the this in your method call with preferencesActivity.this

Comment: If I exchange "this" with "MyPreference.this" Eclipse says "No enclosing instance of the type MyPreference is accessible in scope".

Comment: Try this: Add a SharedPreferences field to your activity. In the onCreate of your Activity initialize it with PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); and then try to access it in the onClick with the field you added.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the integer-array.
I changed it to a string-array and now it works.
This is the code.

array.xml

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="sites_values">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="sites">
        <item>@string/site1</item>
        <item>@string/site2</item>
        <item>@string/site3</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

MyPreference

```
public void public class MyPreference extends PreferenceActivity {
    public static final String DEFAULT_SITE = "1";
    public static final String FAV_SITE = "websites";

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Listener

```
public void click(View v) {
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    String url = "http://";
    if (pref.getString(MyPreference.FAV_SITE, MyPreference.DEFAULT_SITE).equals("1") {
        url = "http://www.google.com";
    } else if (pref.getString(MyPreference.FAV_SITE, MyPreference.DEFAULT_SITE).equals("2")) {
        url = "http://www.youtube.com";
    } else if (pref.getString(MyPreference.FAV_SITE, MyPreference.DEFAULT_SITE).equals("3")) {
        url = "http://www.facebook.com";
    }
    Intent BrowserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(BrowserIntent);
```

}